# Accessing static files (webapp/static/ for inst.) from the web application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I have a web application with a following structure:

```
src
+ main
+-+ java
  + resources
  + webapp
  +-+ WEB-INF
    + static
```

The static directory is server by `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet`, otherwise it is served by the application. What I am trying to achieve, is to access the static directory from the application. However, once it is deployed on the server, the directory seems to be "lost" - I can't access it neither in relative path (by `new File()`) nor in classpath (by new `ClassPathResource()`). I could see, that the directory is missing in the `target` dir, which is probably correct, but I don't know what I can do about it.

Thanks.

**Edit**

1. Maybe it is not clear, but directory `static` is a sibling of WEB-INF and not its child.
2. The static directory might contain 2 GB of images. So it is not desired that this directory should be copied every time the application is deployed (so putting it in the classpath is not probably a good idea).
3. I just can't find the behaviour of DefaultServlet, which I allow to access this directory. Does it copy all the stuff somewhere else? Or does it access it as by absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure WEB-INF isn't visible to the classpath, you'd have to put it in the webapp folder.  Better yet, you probably want to look into using an mvc:resources tag.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Search mvc:resources for an explaination.

**EDIT**

If you place the resource in src/main/resources, they should be available to a ClassPathResource

Comment: Yeah, well it obviously isn't, whole webapp directory is not put in the target directory (so it is not in the classpath). But I can't find any reference to it from the running application...

Comment: placing resources you want into the src/resources directory can be accessed by a classpathresource object.

Comment: Ah interesting. Maybe this would be helpful? Sounds like you might want to deploy it as a seperate servlet that way the war doesnt depend on it. http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Connector2.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized way to access files stored under WEB-INF.  The spirit of the WEB-INF folder is that it contains data that the framework (container/server) reads.  It is not seen as a place for data that the user of the container (you) read directly.  Depending on the container software (and version) that you are using (Tomcat vs. JBoss vs. WebSphere vs. WebLogic, etc), you might be able to kludge your way into WEB-INF, but it would not be portable across containers, and so I would not recommend it.

Consider putting the files somewhere else, such as in the classpath or in a subfolder of the webapp that is not WEB-INF.